# Air vs Titanium vs Phonegap - iPhone performance

Tags: iphone, mobile, air, cordova, titanium

Does anybody have any experience developing with all of these for the iPhone, in particular with regards to the performance of sequential view/image rendering?

For example say a flipbook style app containing 100 slides containing images/videos/text and then quickly swiping through them, with smooth easing transitions between them.

Which technology would be best suited for this?

I have started to play with Titanium and so far it looks very promising, I would very much like to find some more resources about AIR on the iPhone but they seem (for me) to be quite scarce, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used Phonegap and Titanium for iPhone development.

Titanium is a much better choice for your purpose as it runs the UI as native code.

Phonegap will only render your app in webkit, so performance is never going to be optimal.

Another framework you should consider is Corona - which has more in common with Flash than either phonegap or titanium.

Comment: Corona looks very interesting! thanks. I have been using Titanium for a little while now and seems good for iPhone, not so great for android...

Comment: Yes I've heard the same comments re: titanium and Android. However your question only mentions ipHone.

Comment: which is faster air app or titanium app

Answer (score 2):

I have created an app using Titanium, and while it worked pretty good on the iPhone, performance on Android was horrible. I know you asked about iPhone performance, but I guess it's nice to know eh :)

Anyway, Titanium performance will never be equal to true native performance. but very usable.

Comment: cheers, that is good to know especially since I will probably want an Android version later on.

Comment: which one is faster an android app made with air or titanium

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with sequential view/image rendering, but I've been involved in the development of a couple of Phonegap, AIR and Titanium projects, and the winner for me is Titanium.

Phonegap is good, but tends to go sluggish once you start working with a lot of data.

Titanium has been indistinguishable, performance-wise, from a native application for the most part (and easier too!)

I haven't done too much with AIR, but it's reputedly not so good, although the next version of the packager is supposed to be much better.

Comment: Yeah from what I've read Titanium does sound more promising, AIR on the other hand even though I would prefer to use it, does seem to lack responsiveness on some of the demos I've seen, so hopeful for the next version!

Answer (score 1):

i have used PhoneGap and Titanium, in the end I choose Titanium I did write an application requiring a photogallery type od swiping though pages and it works wonderfully.

This is a link to the final application in the app store

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kodak-gallery-quickie/id413197524?mt=8